# How to convert 3 horizontal items vertically when screen shrinks?

Tags: css, responsive

i'm having big issues trying to convert 3 divs from horizontal to vertical. 
The code below shows that for a screen bigger than 1200px, everything works fine.
What i want is a responsive behaviour: by reducing the browser's width, the 3 divs are positioned one below the other. Currently, the code will adjust so that 2 divs are in the first row if there is room for it.

HTML:

```
<div class="example">
    <div class="example-item example-item-1">abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc</div>
    <div class="example-item example-item-2">123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</div>
    <div class="example-item example-item-3">xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz</div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.example {
    background-color: black;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.example-item {
    font-size: 0.7em;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
.example-item-1 {
    background-color: blue;
}
.example-item-2 {
    background-color: red;
}
.example-item-3 {
    background-color: green;
}
```

[Actual result, what i don't want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGOqg.jpg)

[Desire result, what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj2kO.jpg)

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:bootstrap-4]? There aren't any Bootstrap classes being used.

Comment: just because i was trying to use bootstrap before

Comment: Problem solved! i used the Sadegh solution =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this css code and change the "max-width" property with your own decision:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .example-item {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mr_seven/1ktcqay4/2/

you can change result area width to see what will be happened if screen width changes.

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty I would look at using a grid system e.g. bootstraps grid system or even better checkout flex box.

However to simply answer the question you could do this:

```css
.container{
  text-align:center;
}
.box{
  height:20px;
  width:150px;
  border:1px solid black;
  display: block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .box {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
.box1{
  background:steelblue;
}
.box2{
  background:indianred;
}
.box3{
  background:coral;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1"></div>
  <div class="box box2"></div>
  <div class="box box3"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y7c96sp8/